# Windows use Kerberos as a default authentication mechanism. Which one is the default authentication mechanism for Unix/Linux and Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, authentication, kerberos

We know that Windows use Kerberos as a default remote authentication mechanism for authenticating a client to a server? Which one is the default authentication mechanism for Unix/Linux and Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answered my question and I suspect even the down voters know the answer.
Anyway, I'm going to answer my own question (please correct me if I'm wrong), in case it proves beneficial for someone like me.

Since Active Directory (AD) is developed by Microsoft, Windows always use Active Directory (AD) as its domain controller and Kerberos is used in Active Directory as its default authentication mechanism. But not all other operating systems are tied to a single directory service. They use other directory services, in addition to Active Directory, such as Apple Open Directory, Apache Directory Server, 389 Directory Server -previously Fedora Directory Server, Red Hat Directory Server, etc. and almost all of them use/support Kerberos.

Reference:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Open_Directory
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol